# When calling Rest API from Python 2.7 requests, it responds "reason" but I don't see that in my API

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, rest, python-requests

When I call the socialcast api from python 2.7 using requests, I get a response "reason" but I don't see that text in my actual API. Here's my code:

```
import requests
parameters = {"username" = "myUsername", "password" = "myPassword"}
response = requests.get("https://hub.sas.com/api/groups/808/messages.json", parameters)
response.json()
```

The beginning of the JSON that I'm passing through is this:

```
{"messages":[{"id":126433,"user":{"id":4468,"name":
```

So I would expect something else to come back, but what it returns is:

```
{u'reason': u''}
```

Is this an error or is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: What's in `response.status_code`? Is it an empty error message?

Comment: _The beginning of the JSON that I'm passing through is this_ I don't see that you're passing any JSON at all.

Comment: `response.status_code` returns `401`. But my credentials are correct.

@JohnGordon Sorry, I might have worded that wrong. I thought the "https://hub.sas.com/api/groups/808/messages.json" that I am passing through was JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using this code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
r = requests.get('https://hub.sas.com/api/groups/808/messages.json', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
data = r.json()
for message in data['messages']:
      print(message['user']['name'])
```

I'm not sure that the `from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth` or the `data = r.json()` were necessary but it ended up working for me so I left them in there.

Comment: if it solved your issue, then please tick it as answer so that it helps rest of the community.